# Can't code sign helper app properly

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to code sign my helper app.

I've created a separate provisioning profile for it, it is valid and works.
I can archive and export it for Mac App Store submission.

However, when I run the main app, and it adds the helper as a daemon, the helper app starts running, but it doesn't work properly. It pretty much does nothing...

When I disable code sign and leave sandbox checked the helper app works.

I also get a bunch of logs:

---

### Log 1

```
xpcd[236]: 
(null): have symlinks: (
)
```

### Log 2

```
Not allowing process xxxx to launch "/Path/App.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/Helper.app" because it has not been launched previously by the user
```

### Log 3

```
Not allowing process xxxx to register app "Path/App.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/Helper.app" for launch.
```

### Log 4

```
<rdar://problem/11489077> A sandboxed application with pid xxxx, "Helper" checked in with appleeventsd, but its code signature could not be validated ( either because it was corrupt, or could not be read by appleeventsd ) and so it cannot receive AppleEvents targeted by name, bundle id, or signature. Error=ERROR: #100013  { "NSDescription"="SecCodeCopyGuestWithAttributes() returned 100013, -." }  (handleMessage()/appleEventsD.cp #1755) com.apple.coreservices.appleevents.peer.0x7ff7d3b01a60.xpcq
```

---

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Solution

The app HAS to be in the `/Applications` folder for this to work...

Thanks to [Tim Schroeder](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/)!

Comment: @NSAddict - did you have to create a separate AppID and provisioning profile for the helper app? Thanks

Comment: I have done this, and still no luck. I am also running from /Applications, and opening up the .app file and manually launching the helper does work. Any other ideas? Specifically, I am getting log 4 above.

Comment: @RealCasually I wouldn't know, sorry. After this step I everything was working for me.